# Fill the WhoId and WhatId fields when create an event

Tags: apex, unit-test, event

In a test class I need to create an event object, and I want to assign the fields WhoId and WhatId. 
For now I wrote that in my test class:

```
Account c= new Account(FirstName = 'test',
                       LastName = 'test');                               
    insert c;
    Event ev = new Event(StartDateTime = DateTime.now(),
                         EndDateTime = DateTime.now(),
                         Subject = 'Appel',
                         WhoId = c.Id,
                         WhatId = c.Id);
    insert ev;
```

but when I run the test class, I got the error :

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Name ID: incorrect type ID value;: 0017E00000BQTraQAH: [WhoId]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WhoId` for an `event` has to be `leadId or a contactId`.

Create a `contact` record

```
  Contact cnt = new contact();
  Cnt.LastName = 'Test ';
  Insert cnt ;

Even.whoId = cnt.Id;
```

`WhatId` can be `account,opportunity or custom object` reference